# Django: never_cache is not working, it still shows same data on browser back button

Tags: django, django-views, django-class-based-views, django-cache, django-caching

I have a create view which is used to make an object of type Course(model).
i'm using never_cache decorator to reload the page from server everytime i use it.
now if i create a course it gets added in the Course database, now if i press browser back button it still shows me the data with course name that i wrote, which allows me to resubmit the same data, how can i prevent this?(ik i can prevent saving same data twice by overriding save method but i want to prevent user from going back to form in which he entered data).

```
@method_decorator(never_cache, name='dispatch')
class CourseView(CreateView):
    model = Course
    template_name = 'teacher/course.html'
    fields = ['name', 'year']
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs['course_list'] = self.model.objects.all().order_by('name','year')
        return super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        messages.success(self.request, 'Course added successfully.') 
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return self.request.GET.get(key='next', default=reverse('teacher:course'))
```

Answer (score 0):

`never_cache` works normally for requests in future. if you open `CourseView` again, you receive a new data.

Don't forget: When navigating browser history, it restores pages using data cached in **history state** of browser (requests in the past). If you really want to change result of "Back"button in browser - you should interact with history state of browser.

Comment: hello @maxim can u tell me how do i do that?